# Passing Java APM Agent settings in Docker

Tags: spring-boot, docker, apm

I monitor my jar using Elastic APM Agent, i run these commands manually :

```
java -javaagent:../infrastructure/agent/apm-agent.jar \
     -Delastic.apm.service_name=server \
     -Delastic.apm.server_urls=http://${APM_HOST}:8200 \
     -Delastic.apm.application_packages=package.coù \
     -jar ./target/server-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar &
```

Now , i want to pass these parameters using docker run , i create the image and i try with this command to pass these settings , but the application is not starting

```
docker run --name app -e CATALINA_OPTS='-Dspring.config.location=/usr/local/tomcat/application-recette.properties,/usr/local/tomcat/application.yml' 
-e CATALINA_OPTS='-Delastic.apm.service_name=server' 
-e CATALINA_OPTS='-Delastic.apm.server_urls=http://10.128.0.4:8200' 
-e CATALINA_OPTS='-Delastic.apm.application_packages=package.com' 
-d -p 9000:8080 image:v1
```

any idea to resolve this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

actually there are many reasons why your app not starting depending on how you setup and configured your ELK stack , but for me I did the following and it's working fine :

1. shipped **application.jar** and **apm-agent.jar** via Dockerfile and run them inside container :

```
    FROM openjdk:8-jre-alpine
    
    COPY javaProjects/test-apm/target/test-apm-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /app.jar 
    
    COPY elastic-apm-agent-1.19.0.jar /apm-agent.jar 
    
    CMD ["/usr/bin/java","-javaagent:/apm-agent.jar", "-Delastic.apm.service_name=my-cool-service -Delastic.apm.application_packages=main.java -Delastic.apm.server_urls=http://localhost:8200","-jar", "/app.jar"]
```

2. create image from this Dockerfile:

   ```
   docker build -t test-apm:latest ./
   ```
3. run the created image :

   ```
   docker run  --network host -p 8080:8080 test-apm:latest
   ```

- note my **apm-server** and **ELK-stack** was running on my host machine ,
  I think if you do the same and make little changes to mach you environments it should work fine ,

Comment: for the envrionnment variable , how i can pass them ?

Comment: to pass environment variable during running the container I have replaced :
`code`CMD ["/usr/bin/java" ......]  `code` 
with : 

`code`ENTRYPOINT exec /usr/bin/java $JAVA_OPTS -jar /app.jar `code`

then the run command was like this : 


`code`
docker run  -e JAVA_OPTS='-javaagent:/apm-agent.jar \
              -elastic.apm.service_name=my-cool-service \
              -elastic.apm.application_packages=main.java \
              -elastic.apm.server_urls=http://localhost:8200' --network host -p 8080:8080 test-apm:latest`code`

Comment: Work like a charm ; 
Jazak Allahu Khayran

Comment: w -eiakom , nice to hear that's works for you .